# PHP : Get 9 random value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling to get 9 random values from an array, I have this php code which works fine but returns all the values. I need to only select 9 random ones with an foreach preferably.

```
<?php

foreach($gallerystreamobjects as $smallgallery) {   
    $smallgalleryArray = $smallgallery->GalleryPictures;
}

$arr = explode(",", $smallgalleryArray);                

foreach($arr as $value) 
{
    ?>
    <a href="cms/uploads/<?php echo $value;?>" class="swipebox">
        <div class="gallery-item-small" >                           
            <div style="background-image:url('cms/uploads/<?php echo $value;?>')"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php   
}           
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The function [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php) will solve your problem:

```
$randomKeys = array_rand($arr, 9);
foreach($randomKeys AS $key){
    $value = $arr[$key];
    //do whatever you like
}
```

Comment: I tried using the random key but I think there is something about the array that's not working well, still got errors.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use an quick and easy way to do this. Not that its the right way, but ja, so I tried array_rand() but I kept on getting errors on it in its most basic way, I found out it was to do with the values actually going missing. Here is my current solution :

```
<?php

                    $smallgalleryArray = $gallerystreamobjects[0]->GalleryPictures;

                    $arr = explode(",", $smallgalleryArray);            

                    shuffle($arr);
                    $count=0;
                    foreach($arr as $value) {
                        $count++;
                        if($count<10){
                                ?>
                                <a href="cms/uploads/<?php echo $value;?>" class="swipebox">
                                    <div class="gallery-item-small" >                           
                                        <div style="background-image:url('cms/uploads/<?php echo $value;?>')"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <?php   
                            }
                        }           
                    ?>
```